# Turn a string into a tuple

Tags: python, casting

I have a string:

```
s = "(1,2)"
```

How do I turn it into a tuple?
I can't cast it into a tuple, because:

```
tuple(s)
```

turns s into:

```
('(', '1', ',', '2', ')')
```

Comment: strip those brackets away!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that fancy but does the job:

```
s = "(1,2)"    
print(tuple(map(int, s.strip("()").split(","))))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
(1, 2)
```